# why date rangepicker react-dates giving error?

Tags: reactjs

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { DateRangepicker } from 'react-dates';
import {setTextFilter, sortByAmount, sortByDate, setStartDate,setEndDate} from '../actions/filters';

class ExpenseListFilters extends React.Component{
    state={
        calenderFocused:null
    };
    onDatesChange=({startDate,endDate})=>{
        this.props.dispatch(setStartDate(startDate));
        this.props.dispatch(setEndDate(endDate));
    }
    onFocusChange=(calenderFocused)=>{
            this.setState(()=>({calendarFocused}));

    }
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
        <input type="text"  
        value={this.props.filters.text} 
        onChange={(e)=>{
            this.props.dispatch(setTextFilter(e.target.value));
        }}/>
        <select 
        value={ this.props.filters.sortBy } 
        onChange={(e)=>{
            if(e.target.value === 'date'){
                this.props.dispatch(sortByDate());    
            }else if(e.target.value === 'amount'){
                this.props.dispatch(sortByAmount());                
            }
        }}>
            <option value="date">Date</option>
            <option value="amount">Amount</option>
        </select>

        <DateRangepicker
            startDate={this.props.filters.startDate}
            endDate={this.props.filters.endDate}
            onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
            focusedInput={this.state.calenderFocused}
            onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
         />


    </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return{
        filters:state.filters
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ExpenseListFilters);`
```

Comment: Do you have any more details about which line causes that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue that you're seeing is because your import is incorrect. You need to import `DateRangePicker` instead of `DateRangepicker`

> import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-dates';

You can see in [react-dates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dates) for more details.